# Default Devise::SessionsController 'DELETE /users/sign_out' not signing out users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an application with a log out link: `<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete) %>`

Upon clicking the link, I get the following in my dev server logs:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 172.30.0.1 at 2019-03-06 14:52:49 +1300
Processing by Users::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"JLLEb2GSjGuYx+oBhsAkB0jcP0qZCJEUBvuH5VDmCS9Xbwe/hw085gumBPqJmWTtjyFeW1Io81n32NGxDuKjyQ=="}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to https://webdev.test:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

And the root page then loads again, but the user has not signed out.

I opened up a tab in incognito mode in Chrome and tried logging in and logging out, and it worked fine, so it appears to be something specific to my normal-mode browser. I've tried restarting the browser and it doesn't make a difference.

The user account I'm signed in as in Devise is not increasing its sign-in count each time I do this, nor is the updated_at timestamp changing.

I then put `byebug` in my root page controller method and ran the following:

```
   1: class HomeController < ApplicationController
   2:   def index
   3:     byebug
=> 4:     # Omitted for brevity, nothing which touches the current_user object
   5:   end
   6: end
(byebug) Devise.sign_out_all_scopes
true
(byebug) sign_out
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
true
(byebug) continue
```

And confirmed after that, the user still was not signed out.

Restarting the Rails application and trying all the above again resulted in the same outcome, I still can't sign that user out.

Has anyone seen this before and have any ideas on what's getting stuck and how I can sign out?

**Edit**

As requested by a commenter, the routes relating to sign_out:

```
$ rails routes | grep sign_out
          destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                   users/sessions#destroy
$
```

The output of `rails routes | grep destroy_user_session` are identical to the above as well, so it shows there's not a named route directing requests to a different controller action.

And the controller at `app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb` (which only overrides the create method, not the destroy method)

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    # Omitted for brevity
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you run command `rails routes` to print out writes and show only routes related to user sign out? I think you are using another controller Please share destroy method of controller where you override it. As I want to check as it is showing Users::SessionsController#destroy and not Devise::SessionControl#destroy

Comment: I'm not overwriting the destroy method of the SessionsController, only the create method. Will add the routes shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and created user controller to check and seem everything is good. I have only one strange problem, which I am not sure why it is changed. It is about SQL Query. Your response is getting following query.

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

How come it has 4 id as hard coded, normally it should be prepared statement like following

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

So to investigate I will try to use different users to see to login and logout and check if ID is changing or not. If it is not changing then I will investigate where this ID is coming from and why it is hard coded.

Comment: That SQL query is taken straight from the Puma logs, so it's after the string interpolation has occurred.

Comment: You have an issue in not deleting a session, usually ruby on rails create a session with your app name, which has auth information. Obviously when you are in in cognitive mode it is working fine that means the app is ok. You can check your session using developer tools, first login on normal mode and log in, then copy session details on text editor, now log out and see check is there any change. As it is complicated to investigate without codes which is giving error. also try browser by removing cookies of your ruby on rails application using cookie tool than try.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to a button instead of link fixed this issue for me `<%= button_to 'Exit', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>`